# Pro Webmasters swag for top users

Tags: discussion

As a thank you for *being awesome*, if you have at least 950 reputation and are on page 1 or page 2 of …

https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/users?tab=reputation&filter=all

… we'll be sending you a little care package shortly:

- Pro Webmasters Stack Exchange t-shirt in your size
- Pro Webmasters Stack Exchange die-cut, vinyl stickers
- Stack Exchange sharpie
- Stack Exchange pen
- Stack Exchange stickers

You can expect to get an email soon with details on how to confirm and provide your mailing address and size preferences.

### The t-shirt

[image: webmasters.stackexchange.com Tshirt]

[size conversion chart](http://www.meixsell.com/EbayInfo/WWconversion.html) for people outside of the U.S.

### The sticker

[image: webmasters.stackexchange.com sticker]

Congratulations!

<sub>(for anyone else who wants this swag, but isn't on page 1 or page 2 of the all time top users -- the limited edition t-shirts and stickers will be available for purchase from the store soon as well)</sub>

Comment: Well how cool is that! This takes [gamification](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gamification) to a new (nice) level! SE <- No, You Rock!

Comment: Thankyou! Who says digital sharecropping doesn't pay?

Comment: Free swag is the best bit of being a programmer! Thanks :D

Comment: I thought it was a spam mail or a joke, but it's true! Well I really appreciated this, but it's me the one who should say thanks to Stackexchange and to extremely useful sites like Stackoverflow and Webmasters. P.S. Stackexchange rocks!!!

Comment: If this keeps up, Stack Exchange could almost be my tailor :)

Comment: Thanks everyone at Stack Exchange!

Comment: This is really great! Well... i got a question: I use my google account to log in. Which user account should I inform in the first field?

Comment: I had to pick mine up at the post office because it was sent with insufficient postage, but $2 for a t-shirt, sharpie, pen, and stickers is still a pretty good deal!

Answer (score 6):

## Awesome.  Thank you!

Comment: ^ What he said!

Comment: My shirt & swag just arrived!  Thanks again!

Comment: Glad to know that Chris. I'm still waiting for mine all excited.

Answer (score 2):

**The swag, I have it**

[image: Swag package contents]

I had totally forgotten about filling out the form for these goodies earlier in the season, so imagine my surprise when the package appeared outside my door this afternoon!

In addition to the t-shirt, pens, and stickers, there is also a brief letter signed by Joel Spolsky!

Answer (score 2):

Mine just arrived. Post office had a minor issue delivering them (they lost them) but they overcame it.

Answer (score 1):

**Awesome, got it too!** (t-shirt + sticker)

[image]

Comment: Nice! :) Didn't realise they still did this. Any idea what the criteria is these days for "being awesome"? I don't seem to be awesome enough! :/

Comment: @w3d: I got this gift from StackExchange because I participated to the last moderators election. Try your luck to the next one ;-).

Answer (score 0):

I could not hold my breath anymore so I had to ask.

I'm from India & haven't received the goodies yet. I filled my details soon after I got the email, back in October.

Comment: They did say it may take a few weeks. I'd give it a couple more weeks if I were you.

Comment: I've waited and not got it yet :-(